# Why MaxAttemptsExceededException

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue

I don't think I understand Laravel's queue system.

I implemented Redis (basic configuration) and I am doing very basic testing, but this error `MaxAttemptsExceededException`is causing me a lot of confusion.

The idea of this "test" would be to simply run the controller via the browser, and as the controller runs, it "dispatches" the job, inside the `for` loop. In this test, I aim to send 1 email every 25 seconds, I imagine that each time I run the controller, the emails are "stacked".

Initially everything runs, but suddenly, `php artisan queue:work` reports error.

**The point is:**

- What is the reason for this timeout? Is it a delay of Redis?
- Is this parameter correct to use `queue:work --tries=3`?
- Are there any settings I should change?

[image]

**.ENV**

```
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_CONNECTION=default
```

**CONFIG / DATABASE.PHP**

```
    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
        ],

    ],
```

**CONFIG / SESSION.PHP**

```
'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
```

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            $when = now()->addSeconds(25 * $i);

            $mykey = 'KEY--' . $i . '--' . $when->toDateTimeString();

            dispatch(new TestRedisJob($mykey));
        }
```

**MY JOB CLASS (TestRedisJob)**

```
    public function handle(Redis $redis)
    {
        Redis::throttle('email')->allow(1)->every(25)->then(function ()
        {
            \Mail::to('customer@domain.com')
                ->send(new OrderShipped('contato@fiscalizo.com.br', $this->mykey));

        }, function() {
            return $this->release(25);
        });
```

**MY MAILABLE CLASS (OrderShipped)**

```
    public function build()
    {
        return $this
            ->from($this->emailFrom)
            ->subject("Registro Efetivado: " . $this->emailSubject)
            ->view('emails.welcome');
```

Comment: `MaxAttemptsExceededException` means the same job has failed the maximum number of tries and will not be reattempted. In your case, three tries.

Comment: Yes ... I understood that ... but I can not understand what generated the error, is the same email being sent, if sometimes executes, all others should occur. I don't know where to look for the reason error. The table 'failed_job' does not display the information as to why it caused the error, since if there are any errors, I understand that there should have been an error on all attempts.

Comment: Your failed jobs should log to the error log when they fail.

Comment: How are you injecting that `Redis $redis` instance in the `handle()` method? remove it since you're not using it

Comment: I don't know if I correctly understood your question, but in class  TestRedisJob: `use Illuminate\Redis\RedisManager as Redis;`

Comment: You're not even using the manager, you're using the facade in your code